# conditional probability question - expect value

Tags: probability

I got a bit confused in the below question of probability.  Please help me to clarify...thanks!

*May will read either one chapter of history book or one chapter of comics.  If the number of misprints in a chapter of history book and comics are Poisson distributed with mean 2 and 5 respectively, then assuming May is twice likely to choose comics rather than history book, what is the expected number of misprints that May will read?*

Let X be the book May will choose to read, X is Bernoulli distributed.
X=0 for May will read history book, and X=1 for May will read comics.

$p_X=p^{x}(1-p)^{1-x}$

$p_X(1)=2p_X(0)$

then will get the probability of reading history or comics.

now Let Y be the numbers of misprints in a chapter of books,

P(Y|X=0)=poisson(2)

P(Y|X=1)=poisson(5)

I got confused that if $p_{Y|X=0}=\frac{2^y}{y!}e^{-2}$ or $=\frac{2^x}{x!}e^{-2}$?

Here is needed to calculate E(Y), which is $E[E(Y|X)]=\sum_{x=0}^1 p_X(x)\sum_y^\infty y p_{Y|X}(y|x)$, am I right?

Comment: E[Y] = E[Y | Comic] * P[Comic] +  E[Y | History] * P[History]

Comment: then how about P(Y|X)? should it be x! or y!?

Comment: Defining X as bernoulli variable wasn't necessary tbh. Just write P[comic] = $2/3$ and P[history] = $1/3$. So $Y$ is mixture of two Poisson RVs. With probability $2/3, Y$ is Poi(5) and probability $1/3, Y$ is Poi(2). You can read more on the mixture distribution here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution

Comment: Thanks!! I understand now~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for math_noob help, I got the solution now.

as $P(history)=1/3$ and $P(comic) = 2/3$, $Y|Comic \sim Poisson(5), Y|History \sim Poisson(2)$, so $E[Y | Comic]=5$ and $E[Y | History]=2$

the expected number of misprints $E(Y) =  E[Y | Comic] * P[Comic] + E[Y | History] * P[History]$ $=5(2/3)+2(2/3)=4$